# How to reproject an EVF?

Tags: coordinate-system

I have an .evf file and it is not opening in QGIS.

How can we reproject the vector layer (specifically if we want to convert it from lat/lon to UTM projection)?

Comment: Can you provide more details? Is there an error message when you try to open the file?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are dealing with ENVI spatial file - env. Not a shapefile (.shp + .dbf + .shx +...) Im not sure that is supported.

Reprojecting vector in QGIS is easy... Add a dataset into table of contents, right click on it, select save as... then you can choose the file format as well as source and destination projection. Once you save the data into the file, you should have it ready in your new projection.